# Enumerations in schemas using BizTalk WCF Service Publishing Wizard?

Tags: wcf, biztalk, webservice-client, biztalk-2016

I am asked to publish a schema as WCF Service from BizTalk using BizTalk WCF Service Publishing Wizard, and to expose members as enumerations. Idea is to prohibit programmers to give wrong value in specific fields.
I have defined the element type as string, with restriction and a set of values like so:

```
<xs:simpleType name="EventTypes">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="Created"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Changed"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Deleted"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

However, generated client does not pick this up, and programmers are not prohibited to type other values because it is an unrestricted string variable.

Is there any way to publish WCF Service where generated client actually validates input?

Comment: What is the client using the generate the class?   If you try it from Visual Studio does it create a class that does restrict it?

Comment: Could you write another utility class to verify the input value and use the "Add Service Reference" dialog? Or you can verify it in the database.

Comment: Actually, this works, but something was cached/not re-genererated along the way...tricky. I was using Visual Studio to generate client, both when it didn't work and later when it worked. Thanks for feedback!

Comment: See comment by me in Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this works, but something was cached/not re-genererated along the way...tricky. I was using Visual Studio to generate client, both when it didn't work and later when it worked.

Comment: Using WCF Publishing Wizard will always replace restrictions in generated schema, as it will adjust mandatory, non-nullable fields with *Specified members. That is by design.

Will you need Enums and mandatory fields you will have to manually edit generated schemas, but then you will have to control how these calls are made, since the service is "overridden" of its general, safe construction.